# How to code day of the month and send email in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am trying to make it so if I get emailed in the first 15 days of the month, I get a 0 and if I get emailed in the second half of the month, I get a 1.

currently I have
echo date + "%e"/30 | bc -l | mailx -s "Payday yet?" blah@gmail.com

I think I'm just not familiar how to work with the date

Comment: I don't want it to send automatically though, just when I call it

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell `test` command ( or `[ expr ]` which does the same only with an extra `]` as the last argument for sake of looking like a matching pair of brackets).

Something like this should do what you want:

```
[ `date +'%e'` -le 15 ]; FIRST_HALF=$?; mailx -s "Payday = $FIRST_HALF"
```